Movie where main protagonist is recruited in deadly military academy when still very young
Back when I was a kid I saw this movie on TV (must've been like in 2004 or so, and I live in Brazil if that makes a difference), where:

The main character is a man being recruited in something like a very rigid military academy, where he undergoes a series of rigorous tests which includes IQ tests and physical as well
There was a scene where he has to climb to the top of a pit through a rope, but there are other participants trying to do the same, so he has to perforate another man's eyes with his finger in order to keep possession of the rope. The man then falls to the pit and (presumably) dies.

I don't remember much more of it, but I have the impression in my head it's some sort of a "last standing man" kind of movie.
I'm still trying to find it in the internet by myself... but got nothing so far. Thanks anyone in advance.

Was it a World War 2 movie?

Though a few details are a bit off, this is Soldier from 1998 with Kurt Russell.

In 1996, as part of a new military training program, a group of orphaned infants are selected at birth and raised as highly disciplined soldiers with no understanding of anything but military routine. They are trained to be ruthless professionals, and all those considered to be physically or mentally unworthy are executed. The survivors are turned into ultimate fighting machines, but have no understanding of the outside world.

You described a training scene where Sgt. Todd (Russell) climbs a chain and gouges another soldier's eye out. Nevertheless, he fails the challenge and is disposed of, but survives. Here's the trailer:



